# React Native CLI Android APK

Tags: react-native

I am building APK for android in React Native CLI but during the building process. I am getting errors:

---

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processBugsnagE2eFossReleaseManifest'.
 Bugsnag: Your AndroidManifest.xml is missing one or more of
  apiKey/versionCode/buildUuid/versionName/package, which are required to upload to bugsnag.
  apiKey=null
  versionCode=999999999
  buildUUID=beab08fe-8a94-4edf-bb62-ff84eef7bd8f
  versionName=4.24.0
  applicationId=botx7.Chat
```

---

Anyone please guide

Comment: i am also providing Bugsnap api key but the error remains same

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative/issues/3422#issuecomment-957513622

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    ....
    <meta-data android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY" android:value="${BugsnagAPIKey}" />
</application>
```